# How to cancel NSURLSession when moving to another UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am using `NSURLSession` for API call. Once API gets hit, before getting response I am moving to another view controller.  How to stop all `NSURLSession` running in the current view controller? Kindly guide me.

My Sample code is not working. If I move to another `UIViewController`, that new session creates and working fine but previous `UIViewControllers's` session resuming. How to stop that Session? Kindly guide me.

**Sample Get API Cal:**

```
var testSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var testTask = NSURLSessionDataTask()


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        testTask = testSession.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            do{
                let str = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                print(str)
            }
            catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }
        })
        testTask.resume()
    }


override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        testTask.cancel()
        testSession.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the shared session.  Use a real session that you create explicitly.  Then call `invalidateAndCancel` on the session when you no longer need any of its pending requests.